# source code for Codename.one generated apk file

Tags: java, android, codenameone

i am using Codename.one for mobile apps development, once the build is submitted, they provide the "apk" file. Since there are some limitation in codename one, so i was wondering that is there a way to get the native code for android build. ??

Comment: According to their web site this is available for paid accounts only.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the sources using the [include source](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---use-the-include-sources-feature-to-debug-the-native-code-on-iosandroid-etc.html) feature (available for the basic 9 USD subscription) but you would be mistaken to use it for the case described.

You can extend Codename One in any way you want including with native code, there are quite a few [cn1lib](http://codenameone.com/cn1libs.html)'s most of which are open source which demonstrate rather easily how you can write [native code in Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html).

This is a superior approach since it keeps the portability of Codename One and easy development cycle while allowing you to do almost anything you need.

Notice you can look at the full source code of Codename One itself in its [open source project page](http://code.google.com/p/codenameone).